# Java ArrayList avoiding IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist

i got a short question.

```
ArrayList<T> x = (1,2,3,5)

int index = 6
if (x.get(6) == null) {
    return 0;
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 4
```

How can I avoid this? I just want to check if there is something in the array with index 6. If there is (null)/(nothing there) i want to return 0.

Comment: You can put condition on the size of the list.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use the size of the list (it's not an array):

```
if (x.size() <= index || x.get(index) == null) {
    ...
}
```

Or if you want to detect a valid index with a non-null value, you'd use:

```
if (index < x.size() && x.get(index) != null) {
    ...
}
```

In both cases, the `get` call will *not* be made if the first part of the expression detects that the index is invalid for the list.

Note that there's a logical difference between "there is no element 6" (because the list doesn't have 7 elements) and "there is an element 6, but its value is null" - it may not be important to you in this case, but you need to understand that it *is* different.

Comment: If x.size() == 6 then x.get(6) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas: Good job that my code won't call `x.get(6)` in that situation then, isn't it? If `x.size() == 6`, then `x.size() <= 6` will be true, so the second operand of the `||` won't be evaluated.

Comment: Still looks very twisted. Your own second example is much easier to read.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas: The second example is the inverse though - look at the OP's original code; he's trying to detect the *absence* of a non-null value. That's the case if either the index is out of range *or* the result is null. Yes, it could be written as `if (index >= x.size() ...)` if you'd prefer that, but it would still fundamentally be a condition of "if the index is out of range" vs the second snippet of "if the index is *in* range".

Answer (score 2):

check size of arraylist. if size is less that 6 then return 0 else return value

Comment: Less or equal (off by one).

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of the list first by using [`size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29), then check for the index.

```
if (x.size() <= 6 || x.get(6) == null) {
    return 0;
}
```